# Connecting c++ program with Oracle using occi library

Tags: c++, oracle, g++, mingw-w64, occi

I'm trying to connect my C++ program to Oracle database(12.1).

My C++ program at the moment is (I am using mingw64 g++ compiler in windows):

```
#include <occi.h> 

void oracle_connect()
{
    using namespace oracle::occi;       
    using namespace std;
    Environment *env;              
    Connection *conn;              
    Statement *stmt;               
    env = Environment::createEnvironment (Environment::DEFAULT);
    conn = env->createConnection ("dasdas", "dasdas", "dasdas");
}

int main()
{
    oracle_connect();
}
```

I compile my program using this command:

```
g++ test.cpp -loci -lociw32 -loraocci12
```

All those libraries (oraocci12.lib ociw32.lib oci.lib) are from my oracle folder:
oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\oci\lib\msvc

But I got error during compilation:

```
undefined reference to `oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned int), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned int), void (*)(void*, void*))'
```

How should I properly link over my program to successfuly compile it?

Comment: Have you tried Adding -L also (something like -Ld:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\oci\lib\msvc)

Comment: @Gojita I tried now g++ test.cpp -LC:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\oci\lib\msvc -loci -lociw32 -loraocci12 - same error.

Comment: Try to find in your directory the library where is define the function. make sure also that the oracle library is compiled with an ABI version identical to the g++ you use. What version of g++ do you use ?

Comment: @Gojita, g++ version is 8.1.0.
Which directory to search for the definition do you mean?

Comment: The one where the library (oraocci12.lib, etc) are. But I'm afraid that you have to use the same compiler as Oracle did to link there libraries. I'm not sure g++ 8.1.0 is ABI compatible (I do not know which compiler oracle use on windows).

Comment: Interesting situation. Do you have any recommendations on it? I'm sure, that definition is in oraocci12.lib. Moreover I tryied to convert those libs in .a format and link my program against them. The result was that compiler told that those converted .a libs was not compatible.

Comment: The only thing I can think about is to use MS visual studio to build your application (I don't know if there's any free version of visual studio aroud)

Answer (score 1):

In the project I am working the config is the following

```
#----- Environnement specifique Oracle -----
ORACLEINC    = $(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/include
ORACLELIB    = $(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/lib32
ORACLEBIN    = $(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/bin
ORAINC = -I$(ORACLEINC) -I$(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/rdbms/demo -I$(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/precomp/public -I$(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/plsql/public -I$(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/network/public
ORALIB = -L$(ORACLELIB) -L$(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/rdbms/lib -L$(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/precomp/lib -L$(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/plsql/lib -L$(ORACLE_HOME_DEV)/network/lib
```

where `ORACLE_HOME_DEV --> /exec/products/oracle/v10.2/`

The library you are looking for shoule be here

`libocci.a.10.1 -> /exec/products/oracle/v10.2/lib32/libocci.a`

Comment: in my oracle distribution (v 12.1) there are no such directories, which you mentioned.